# delaying the callback function in for loop without async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a function called printLetters which prints letters after 1000ms. I expected it to print letters one at a time with a 1000ms delay, but it prints all letters at once. How do I make it resolve each with delay **without async/await?**

```js
const printLetters = (letters) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < logs.length; i++) {
    delay(1000).then(() => {
      console.log(logs[i]);
      })
  }
}

const delay = (t) => {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, t))
}

const arr = ['a','b','c']

printLetters(arr)
```

Comment: `delay(1000).then` means that all iterations will wait for 1 second, then all will resolve at the same time and log

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks for your reply. Is there any way to make it resolve one at a time with a 1-second delay for each interval or is it just not possible?

Comment: See the canonical

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry but don't really see the answer I am looking for. So the delay with interval is only possible with async/await and not with .then()?

Comment: It's possible with `.then` (just multiply the timeout for each iteration), but `await` is a much, much cleaner approach

Comment: Could you show me the example code with `.then()`?